# An .exe file generated by MinGW g++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, security, g++

recently, when I compile any file in CodeBlocks (using `mingw32-g++.exe`), when I execute the generated .exe file, the executable starts but does nothing. Then, when I close it, it seems that it is opened somewhere by an another program, because I am not able to rebuild the file without restarting the computer first. Maybe that issue is caused by a certain security application? I have Avast installed and earlier it analysed once the executable in Sandbox, but now the Sandbox doesn't start, although in Avast statistics I can see that the .exe file is scanned.

Thank you for any good advice.

Comment: Try adding some output to the early part of the program (like the first thing you do), does it come out? Have you tried looking in the task-manager to see if your program i still running? Tried to kill it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading your question, I determined to ask you that Avast is running on your PC or not!

And at the end I got my answer. This is a common problem of avast. So, disable Avast while running code in codeblocks.

TO be more specific:

> Maybe that issue is caused by a certain security application?

Yes, and it is Avast.